# GWT RPC serialization for Dynamic Host Page

Tags: java, gwt, serialization, pojo, gwt-rpc

I implemented a **Dynamic Host Page**  (http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/dynamic_host_page.html) in my GWT project to pass my **User** POJO object directly in it.

I did it with AutoBean (https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/AutoBean) so I had to declare and implement **Interfaces**

But I found this way a little bit too verbose.

Is there another way? I mean **GWT RPC** do serialization without **Interfaces** so can I use it?

Another point; I already use the **gwt-storage lib** (https://github.com/seanchenxi/gwt-storage) that uses the **GWT RPC mechanisim** to store Java POJO Object in the Browser so there is probably an easy way...

THX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So thx you @xi-chen and @richard-wallis

Part of the solution were discussed on **gwt-storage github repo** (https://github.com/seanchenxi/gwt-storage/issues/8#issuecomment-68443910)

So it's totally possible with **GWT RPC mechanism** + **gwt-storage**:

**index.jsp**

```
<%@page import="com.google.gson.Gson"%>
<%@page import="com.learnkeeper.server.ServiceImpl"%>
<%@page import="com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC"%>
<%@page import="com.learnkeeper.shared.entities.User"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<%
  Object user = request.getSession().getAttribute("user");
  String serialized_user = new Gson().toJson(RPC.encodeResponseForSuccess(ServiceImpl.class.getMethod("getUser"), user).substring("//OK".length()));
%>
<script type="text/javascript">var serialized_user=<%=serialized_user%>;</script>
</head>
<body>
```

> Notice you have to remove the **//OK** substring at the beginning of **RPC.encodeResponseForSuccess** result.

**User.java**

```
public class User implements IsSerializable {
}
```

> Notice you have to implement **IsSerializable** (**Serializable** is not enough)

**HostPageUtils.java**

```
public class HostPageUtils {
  private static final native String getSerializedUser() /*-{
        return $wnd.serialized_user;
  }-*/;

  public static User getUser() {
    final String serializedUser = getSerializedUser();
    StorageSerializer storageSerializer = GWT.create(StorageSerializer.class);
    try {
      return storageSerializer.deserialize(User.class, serializedUser);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new RuntimeException();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to reuse GWT's com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter to serialize your POJO objects into string and put it into your dynamic host page.

Then you can use com.seanchenxi.gwt.storage.client.serializer.StorageSerializer to do the deserialization.

To get an instance of StorageSerializer, you should use GWT.create(StorageSerializer.class);